# Error running a R Scripts in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, error, qgis-processing

I have developed script in R but I am unable to run it in QGIS.

It shows an error that R is not available even though it is installed in my laptop?

What is the solution?

Comment: You need to add more info about exactly what you are trying, the error messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your script must be into the rscript's folder (on unix, something like: /home/YOU/.qgis2/processing/rscripts).
"R scripts" must be activate on processing's options.